# react native firebase storage - unknown error

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I'm building a react native app with firebase storage and i'm trying to 1) store the image in storage, 2) retrieve downloadURL, 3) set the downloadURL string in firebase for access via the database

```
storage().ref('users').child(userKey + '/profileImage').put(image.path).then(() => {
    storage().ref('users').child(userKey + '/profileImage').getDownloadURL().then(image => {
        setProfileImage(image)
        firestore().collection('users').doc(userKey).set({
            profileImage: image
        }).catch((e) => console.log('uploading image error1 => ', e));
    }).catch((e) => console.log('uploading image error2 => ', e));
}).catch((e) => console.log('uploading image error3 => ', e));
```

I'm getting the following error at the first storage
call[image]

Answer (score 0):

What value and type is your `image.path` variable. If you look at the documentation for [`Reference.put`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.storage.Reference#put) you can see that it accepts `Blob | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer` and I somewhat doubt that `image.path` is one of those types.

Answer (score 0):

`image.path` is reference to device storage and not contains actually image data.

Assume that `image.path` is reference of image to device storage
like `file://path/to/file`.

It required to fetch image raw data either as Blob | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer.

For Sake of simplicity, let fetch image raw data as BLOB.

```js
const imgRef = firebase.storage().ref("");
// Indicate  content type extension to encode final image -JPEG,PNG
const metadata = { contentType: "image/jpg" };

const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
    resolve(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
  };
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.open("GET", image.path, true);
  xhr.send(null);
});


// BLOB data are ready, upload to remote firebase server
imgRef.put(blob, metadata);

// We're done with the blob, close and release it
blob.close();
```